# How to filter records in Hive using spark

Tags: apache-spark, hive, apache-spark-sql, hiveql

Why is the sting not getting compared?

I have my input as -

```
+-------+
|      y|
+-------+
| ""no""|
| ""no""|
| ""no""|
|""yes""|
| ""no""|
| ""no""|
| ""no""|
| ""no""|
|""yes""|
| ""no""|
| ""no""|
| ""no""|
| ""no""|
|""yes""|
| ""no""|
| ""no""|
+-------+
```

And I am querying-

```
sqlContext.sql("select count(y) from dummy where y='yes'").show()
```

And the output is -

```
+---+
|_c0|
+---+
|  0|
+---+
```

`y` is declared as string type in DDL

Comment: Should've used `.replaceAll("\"\"", "")` earlier :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try this:

```
sqlContext.sql("select count(y) from dummy where y='\"\"yes\""'").show()
```

Note that your data has `""yes""` not just `yes`.

You still need cleansing of your data :)

Or do this way:

```
sqlContext.sql("select count(y) from dummy where y like '%yes%'").show()
```

Comment: YOu may `ACCEPT` the answer or upvote, if this works as per question, and in your case.